# Deserializing a simple JSON array with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm sure this question has been asked over and over again, but for some reason, I still can't manage to get this to work.

I want to deserialize a JSON object that contains a single member; a string array:

```
{"results" : ["a", "b"]}
```

This is the class that I'm trying to deserialize into:

```
public class Whatever {
    [DataMember(Name = "results")]
    public string[] Results { get; protected set; }
}
```

And this is the Deserialize method:

```
private static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(instance.GetType());
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

A call like `Deserialize<Whatever>("{\"results\" : [\"a\", \"b\"]}")` is returning an initialized instance of `Whatever` but the `Results` array is staying `null`.

Is there something wrong with the structure of `Whatever`?

Comment: You don't need `var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` use `typeof(T)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ah, after posting this I realized that I was missing the `DataContract` attribute decoration on `Whatever`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Whatever {
    [DataMember(Name = "results")]
    public string[] Results { get; protected set; }
}
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks. It is also crucial to map the names of data members case sensitive. You have done that, however I want to stress this in case someone tries to use DataContract and DataMember, but forgets the Name attribute (as I have done the first time).

Answer (score 11):

i know, the post is quite barred; but:
also possible to directly return a list of class-objects, if you got an jsonarray-string of information to bind to a dataclass; i.e.:

```
List<SomeDataClass> filesToMove = new List<SomeDataClass>();

public T deserializeJSON<T>(string json)
{
    var instance = typeof(T);
    var lst = new List<SomeDataClass>();

     using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
     {
         var deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(instance);
         return (T)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);
     }
}

someJsonArrayString = "[{\"ID\":7},{\"ID\":16}]";
filesToMove = deserializeJSON<List<SomeDataClass>>(someJsonArrayString);
Console.WriteLine(filesToMove[1].ID); // returns 16
```

with dataclass SomeDataClass.cs:

```
[DataContract]
class SomeDataClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Whats with the List, your example does not work like you have posted it.