# How can I serialise a string array to JSON using DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, datacontractserializer

This seems to be the same question as below but that answer hasn't resolved it:

[Deserializing a Simple JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204320/deserializing-a-simple-json-array-with-datacontractjsonserializer)

I am using DataContractJsonSerializer to convert from XML to JSON and vice versa. Everything works with complex data types and arrays of complex data types but I'm having a problem producing JSON for a string array.

The JSON I need to produce should have this structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "x_axis": {
      "labels": [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr","May", "Jun", "Jul", Aug","Sep", Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ]
     }
  }
}
```

The objects I am using are:-

LineChartData:

```
[DataContract]
public class LineChartData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "x_axis")]
    public LineChartXAxis XAxis { get; set; }
}
```

LineChartXAxis:

```
[DataContract]
public class LineChartXAxis
{
    [DataMember(Name = "labels")]
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }
}
```

The XML I am trying to convert looks like this:

```
<LineChartData>
  <XAxis>
    <Labels>Jan</Labels>
    <Labels>Feb</Labels>
    <Labels>Mar</Labels>
    <Labels>Apr</Labels>
    <Labels>May</Labels>
    <Labels>Jun</Labels>
    <Labels>Jul</Labels>
    <Labels>Aug</Labels>
    <Labels>Sep</Labels>
    <Labels>Oct</Labels>
    <Labels>Nov</Labels>
    <Labels>Dec</Labels>
  </XAxis>
</LineChartData>
```

My deserialising code is:

```
var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LineChartData));
var stringReader = new StringReader(xml);

var result = serialiser.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

The JSON I get back always has an empty labels array:

```
{
  "data": {
    "x_axis": {
      "labels":[]
    }
  }
}
```

How should I be defining the Labels property in LineChartXAxis to serialise the JSON correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues here:

1. Your `<Labels>` collection does not have an outer container element.  By default `XmlSerializer` adds a container element when serializing a collection.  To skip the outer wrapper element, add an `[XmlElement("Labels")]` attribute to the `Labels` property.  ([XML serializer attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are mutually independent and may both be applied without one set affecting the other.)

   I.e. your actual problem is in reading your list of strings from XML not writing then to JSON.
2. Your JSON has an outer root element corresponding to the `{"data": {...}}` object. You need to account for this when serializing.  (Maybe you do and this is not shown.)

Thus the following should work:

```
[DataContract]
public class LineChartData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "x_axis")]
    public LineChartXAxis XAxis { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class LineChartXAxis
{
    [DataMember(Name = "labels")]
    [XmlElement("Labels")]
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class RootObject<T>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public static class RootObjectExtensions
{
    public static RootObject<T> FromData<T>(T data)
    {
        return new RootObject<T> { Data = data };
    }
}
```

And then use them like

```
        var data = xmlString.LoadFromXML<LineChartData>();
        var jsonString = DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.GetJson(RootObjectExtensions.FromData(data));
```

With extension methods:

```
public static class XmlSerializerHelper
{
    public static T LoadFromXML<T>(this string xmlString, XmlSerializer serial = null)
    {
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            object result = (serial ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}

public static class DataContractJsonSerializerHelper
{
    public static string GetJson<T>(T obj, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            (serializer ?? new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T))).WriteObject(memory, obj);
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Incidentally, as an alternative, you could look at [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which has the ability to [convert directly between JSON and XML](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm).

Comment: dbc, that XmlElement attribute was exactly what I needed. Thanks for your response. I have left the rest of my code unaltered, without the extension methods, because it is now working perfectly.

Comment: We've made a company decision to use the native .NET libraries instead of Json.NET, which is why I'm doing it with DataContractSerializer, but I do use Json.NET for testing and debugging and that is how I created the XML I'm using for testing, knowing it should produce the required JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Traditional arrays are not easily resized and I think that is the reason the serializer is having issues. Change your `Labels` property to be a `List<string>` instead and that should work.

Comment: viggity, thanks for the response. I tried that and it still didn't work so it doesn't appear to be the array structure that's the problem in this case.